# Get Text dimmensions on CCTextFieldTTF

Tags: cocos2d-x, cclabelttf

Hi I want to know the width of the text inside the CCTextFieldTTF but I can't find a way to do it, I want this width so I can move a CCLabelTTF in that position so it can be like a cursor for the CCTextFieldTTF

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I came up with an idea that really works

In CCTextFieldTTF.h declare a new method

```
float getTextDimensions();
```

And in your .cpp

```
float CCTextFieldTTF::getTextDimensions()
{
    return CCLabelTTF::getContentSize().width;
}
```

And know just call your CCTextFieldTTF object

```
m_pTextField->getTextDimensions()
```

And do whatever you like with it

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
float labelWidth = label.contentSize.width;
```

;)